# How to vertically align Bootstrap 4 card title text to bottom

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-cards

I have four Bootstrap 4 cards lined up, but the title for just one of the cards wraps to a second line. How can I code this so that all four card titles are flush bottom?

I tried setting the height of each card to a certain pixel height and then applied vertical-align: bottom, but that's not working.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="card-group">
    <div class="card img-fluid">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/260x313.png?text=placeholder+image" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h5 class="card-title">FIRST CARD</h5>
        <hr>
        <p class="card-text">Tech virtual drone online browser platform through in a system. Document fab developers encryption smartphone powered, bespoke blockstack edit atoms.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card img-fluid">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/260x313.png?text=placeholder+image" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h5 class="card-title">SECOND CARD</h5>
        <hr>
        <p class="card-text">But stream software offline. Professor install angel sector anywhere create at components smart.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card img-fluid">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/260x313.png?text=placeholder+image" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h5 class="card-title">THIRD CARD WITH MUCH LONGER TITLE</h5>
        <hr>
        <p class="card-text">Document fab developers encryption smartphone powered, bespoke blockstack edit atoms.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card img-fluid">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/260x313.png?text=placeholder+image" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
      <div class="card-img-overlay">
        <h5 class="card-title">FOURTH CARD</h5>
        <hr>
        <p class="card-text">Now digital designs id anywhere atoms. Now strategy startups documents designs. Venture crypto adopters niche. Video algorithm system ultra-private policies engineering.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a Codepen: https://codepen.io/Codewalker/pen/RXxaVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I code this so that all four card titles are flush bottom.

**Case 1: If the title of your content is not dynamic.**

If you want to make the card flush to bottom. You need to set its `height` and use `flexbox` to flush it to bottom.

See the code below.

```css
.card-title-cont{
  height: 50px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>




<div class="container">
          <div class="card-group">
                <div class="card img-fluid">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/260x313.png?text=placeholder+image" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                  <div class="card-title-cont">
                    <h5 class="card-title">FIRST CARD</h5>
                  </div>
                  <hr>
                  <p class="card-text">Tech virtual drone online browser platform through in a system. Document fab developers encryption smartphone powered, bespoke blockstack edit atoms.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card img-fluid">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/260x313.png?text=placeholder+image" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                  <div class="card-title-cont">
                    <h5 class="card-title">SECOND CARD</h5>
                  </div>
                  <hr>
                  <p class="card-text">But stream software offline. Professor install angel sector anywhere create at components smart.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card img-fluid">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/260x313.png?text=placeholder+image" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                  <div class="card-title-cont">
                    <h5 class="card-title">THIRD CARD WITH MUCH LONGER TITLE</h5>
                  </div>
                  <hr>
                  <p class="card-text">Document fab developers encryption smartphone powered, bespoke blockstack edit atoms.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card img-fluid">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/260x313.png?text=placeholder+image" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                  <div class="card-title-cont">
                    <h5 class="card-title">FOURTH CARD</h5>
                  </div>
                  <hr>
                  <p class="card-text">Now digital designs id anywhere atoms. Now strategy startups documents designs. Venture crypto adopters niche. Video algorithm system ultra-private policies engineering.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>  
          </div>
```

---

**Case 2: If the title of your content is dynamic.**

I suggest you need to style your title to `text-overflow: ellipsis;` since the content is dynamic.

```css
.card-title{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="container">
          <div class="card-group">
                <div class="card img-fluid">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/260x313.png?text=placeholder+image" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                  <h5 class="card-title">FIRST CARD</h5>
                  <hr>
                  <p class="card-text">Tech virtual drone online browser platform through in a system. Document fab developers encryption smartphone powered, bespoke blockstack edit atoms.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card img-fluid">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/260x313.png?text=placeholder+image" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                  <h5 class="card-title">SECOND CARD</h5>
                  <hr>
                  <p class="card-text">But stream software offline. Professor install angel sector anywhere create at components smart.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card img-fluid">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/260x313.png?text=placeholder+image" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                  <h5 class="card-title">THIRD CARD WITH MUCH LONGER TITLE</h5>
                  <hr>
                  <p class="card-text">Document fab developers encryption smartphone powered, bespoke blockstack edit atoms.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="card img-fluid">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/260x313.png?text=placeholder+image" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
                <div class="card-img-overlay">
                  <h5 class="card-title">FOURTH CARD</h5>
                  <hr>
                  <p class="card-text">Now digital designs id anywhere atoms. Now strategy startups documents designs. Venture crypto adopters niche. Video algorithm system ultra-private policies engineering.</p>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>  
          </div>
```

Hopes this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the content for your card's title is dynamic so I don't think you can really foresee how much height is enough.

I would just go for "truncating the text with an ellipsis" approach with a `title`:

```html
<h5 class="card-title text-truncate" title="THIRD CARD WITH MUCH LONGER TITLE">
    THIRD CARD WITH MUCH LONGER TITLE
</h5>
<hr>
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/fdwshkzo/5/